# Video can't be open in allure reporter using wdio-video-reporter

Tags: javascript, video, webdriver-io, allure, reporters

I have problem when using wdio-video-reporter.

I'm using allure reporter and want to add video reporter to it. I've read and follow instruction from documentation wdio website https://webdriver.io/es/docs/wdio-video-reporter/.

Here are my configure in wdio.config.js

```
const video = require('wdio-video-reporter');

reporters: [
    [videos, {
      saveAllVideos: true,
      videoSlowdownMultiplier: 3,
    }],
    ['allure', {
      outputDir: './allure-results',
      disableWebdriverStepsReporting: true,
      disableWebdriverScreenshotsReporting: true,
      useCucumberStepReporter: true,
      addConsoleLogs: true,
    }],
]
```

I found some stack here. I found in my allure report, the video like this can't open
[video can't open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URFHV.png).

And in My Terminal have error like this.

```
[0-39] node:internal/process/promises:279
[0-39]             triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
[0-39]             ^
[0-39] 
[0-39] Protocol error (Target.activateTarget): Target closed.
[0-39] ProtocolError: Protocol error (Target.activateTarget): Target closed.
[0-39]     at /home/ferdian/Documents/Automate/web-automation/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:230:24
[0-39]     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
[0-39]     at CDPSession.send (/home/ferdian/Documents/Automate/web-automation/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:226:16)
[0-39]     at Page._screenshotTask (/home/ferdian/Documents/Automate/web-automation/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:1984:28)
[0-39]     at /home/ferdian/Documents/Automate/web-automation/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:1981:62
[0-39]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
[0-39]   originalMessage: '',
[0-39]   [Symbol(originalCallSite)]: [
[0-39]     CallSite {},
[0-39]     CallSite {},
[0-39]     CallSite {},
[0-39]     CallSite {},
[0-39]     CallSite {},
[0-39]     CallSite {}
[0-39]   ],
[0-39]   [Symbol(mutatedCallSite)]: [
[0-39]     CallSite {},
[0-39]     CallSite {},
[0-39]     CallSite {},
[0-39]     CallSite {},
[0-39]     CallSite {},
[0-39]     CallSite {}
[0-39]   ]
[0-39] }
```

What should i do for this error? where i must add some setting to add video reporting. Because I read in the documentation say like this:

> Adding the Allure reporter as well, automatically updates the reports with videos without any need to configure anything :-)

I already try use any version of wdio-video-reporter, but it can't solved.

I expect i can use video reporter that include in allure reporter.

Thankyou.